# SQL - Query to get only that data which contains all the listed values given in 'IN' operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has list of accounts in one column (Account_ID), and different type of transaction codes (Transaction_Cd) in another column. There are total 23 different values for Transaction_Cd (1,5,7,8,9-27). An account can have multiple rows with any of these transaction_cd. I want to write a query that will output an account that contains at least 10 of these different transaction_cd.

I tried with IN operator, but it will give me output for even the account which has only 1 of the 23 transaction type, but that's not what I need. Want account that will have at least 10 different transaction codes.

I hope my question makes sense. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If your `Account_ID` column is a varchar storing a string of comma-delimited values (a guess, you haven't clarified) then you have a typical anti-pattern and will have many issues, the first of which is not understanding how `in` works.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(DISTINCT <expression>)` will work in this case. For example:

```
select account_id
from t
group by account_id
having count(distinct transaction_cd) >= 10
```

See [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jkor65AU9pZEkA9wL5CAQR/0).